# Pandas data frame and series

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

The pandas data frame is of 30 rows after reading the excel file. It filters to one row (it will always be one row after a filter), how can i retain the data frame as data frame. After the filter (deletion of rows) it converts the data frame to series.

The excel file ppfileloc has 30 rows for the month of april and for a selected date it will always be one record in the data frame. The resulting data frame reshapes to series.

```
#Following is the code and output in jupyter. 

df = pd.read_excel(ppfileloc)
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
date = 15
df1 = df.loc[date,:]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df3 = df2.drop(labels=['Day', 'Sunrise', 'Sunset   ', 'SidTime    '])

df3.shape
# (8, 1)

#df3 command fetches the following as output
df3  

#         15
# Sun       000:37:56
# Moon      119:42:25
# Mars      045:36:33
# Mercury   333:14:41
# Jupiter   240:11:57
# Venus     329:01:24
# Saturn    266:12:49
# Rahu      087:52:24
```

How can I convert `df3` to two columns with planet and degrees as columns titles?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a `Series` to a `DataFrame`, you can just do `series.to_frame()`. This accepts a `name` argument to say what to name single column of the dataframe. This will leave the index as an index. Since you want it as a column instead, you have to reset the index as well and then rename it as you want.

```py
df3.to_frame(name="degrees").reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "planet"})
```

Comment: Thank you @ Nathan, i do not have to have df3. Instead i dropped the labels in df1 and converted into df2 as dataframe with column names and index. df2 gives the desired output.

import pandas as pd
ppfileloc = (r"C:\Users\Aomine\djangoproject\djangoproject\Files\textppapr2019.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(ppfileloc)
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
date = 15
df1 = df.loc[date,:]
df1 = df1.drop(labels=['Day', 'Sunrise', 'Sunset   ', 'SidTime    '])
df2 = df1.to_frame(name="degrees").reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "planet"})